# DialogFragment: Keyboard hides automatically after typing numbers in edittext

Tags: android-edittext, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment

I have a very simple fragmentDialog with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:background="@color/note"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/post_it_note_area"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:textColor="@color/gray_text_primary"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

But when I type a number in the editText the keyboard will automatically close.
From the log I get:

```
W/ViewRootImpl? Dropping event due to no window focus: KeyEvent { action=ACTION_DOWN, keyCode=KEYCODE_7, scanCode=0, metaState=0, flags=0x6, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1548366109, downTime=1548366109, deviceId=-1, source=0x0 }
W/IInputConnectionWrapper? showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
```

I'm running android 4.4.4 on a Moto X 2013. 
What cause this weird behavior? How can I avoid the keyboard hiding?

**EDIT:** 
It's not the keyboard that closes as I digit the number but the whole app (no crashes). I also noticed that the app closes when I type a number alone and not if I type a number near a letter: "hello a6" -> ok, "hello 6" -> closes immediatly). I added a textwatcher to the editText and none of the methods of the listener are triggered.. Please help me!

**EDIT 2:**
I tried now with a Samsung S5 with Android 5 and the issue is not presenting, maybe something related to the Android version or the device?

**EDIT 3:**
Bad news, the issue is presenting again on the S5 if I type the delete or the "Sym" keys.. Same as before, the app closes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.. Finally I found what caused this behavior..

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.setOnKeyListener(new DialogInterface.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            getActivity().finish();

            return true;

        }

    });

    return dialog;

}
```

I made this code for closing the dialogFragment pressing the back key and it's obviously buggy.
Strange thing is that I would expect from thisto finish the activity typing any character..